# Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function on real number line such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = a$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function on real number line such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = a$.Then which of following is true ?

A. $a$ must be 0

B. $a$ is greater than 1

C. $a$, need not to be zero but $|a|$ is less than 1

D. $a$ is less than -1

I took $f(x)=1$ and a comes out to be zero.  But I am not sure

Thanks

Comment: The asymptote line to $f(x)$ is $y=1$ and the slope of this line is $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $f'(n+\theta_n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$ by the mean value theorem and its consequences for the limit.

Comment: can you give counter examples

Comment: This provides a (hint towards a) proof -- why do you need a counterexample? And a counterexample to what?

Comment: Can you please add more details

Comment: Use the mean value theorem on $f(n+1)-f(n)$ to get the above. Then, take the limit on both sides: what constraint does it give on $a$?

Comment: @ClementC. why did you choose this interval

Comment: I cannot say for sure why @LutzL chose it, but the reason I would put forward is that you want to difference $x-y$ in the application of the MVT to be a constant -- so that you only have $f^\prime$ on one side of the equality.

Comment: @ClementC.: Yes, and it is standard procedure for proofs of this statement. Lots of duplicates if one cared to search for it.